# Assumption of asymptotic flatness

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, curvature, boundary-conditions

Why is asymptotic flatness a good assumption for solving Einstein's field equations? Intuitively it makes sense to me but I am looking for a formal justification.
(By asymptotic flatness I mean that the metric is Minkowskian at large distances.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to solve EFE completely: we are seeking *a* solution, not *all* solutions.

Also, we want a special solution satisfying the following: the gravitational effects of a star/black hole/etc. have be negligible at huge distances, because the effects of distant attractors doesn't play a major role in our life (indeed, experimentalists put major effort into discovering these objects).

In mathematical language this requirement is exactly asymptotic flatness.

Comment: Well, it has to be asymptotically a cosmological solution, not necessarily flat. Asymptotic flatness is the simplest but it's not necessarily the most realistic of assumptions.

Comment: @Slereah good point, but the context of the question is IMO clear: OP wants to know why we impose asymptotic flatness for gravitating-center kinds of solutions.